# ¿Cómo hacer que no se muestren los valores que se ingresa por teclado?

Tags: python, input

```
print("Ingrese las coordenadas: ")
valor_1 = input()
valor_2 = input()
print(f"\n{valor_1},{valor_2}")
```

Los números en color verde representan los valores ingresados por el usuario. Como puedo solicitar estos valores y que sean únicamente visibles cuando yo los muestre por pantalla.

[image]

Comment: @Israel es muy útil que edites las publicaciones, haces un gran trabajo. Cuando estés en cosas de Python, si puedes aprovecha para poner la etiqueta [tag:python], independientemente de que ya haya de versiones específicas. ¡Gracias!

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar', Claro lo tomo en cuenta. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar la función `getpass()` del módulo `getpass`, el cual viene incluido por defecto en la distribución estándar de Python. [Este módulo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html) está en realidad pensado para hacer inputs de contraseñas, pero funciona para lo que deseas acá.

Lo puedes usar de la siguiente manera:

```
from getpass import getpass


print("Ingrese coordenadas")
valor_1 = getpass('')
valor_2 = getpass('')

print(f"\n{valor_1},{valor_2}")
```

**Ten en cuenta** que getpass no podrá esconder el input stream si lo usas en la consola interactiva de Python, o un REPL. Por lo tanto, ejecuta tu archivo desde un terminal. Es decir, (en Linux) ve al directorio donde tienes el archivo y haz:

```
$ python3 el_nombre_de_tu_archivo.py
```

Comment: Y hay alguna forma de evitar el salto de linea cuando se ingresa el valor, por ejemplo: print("caracteres", end=" ")  con end en el print se puede evitar, hay alguna forma de hacerlo con el input o el getpass?

Comment: Usando este enfoque, con este módulo, no :( Pero quizás de otra manera sea posible.